# Angular2 Material: iterating through select options

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a select options list that is opened through the method open() but I also want to iterate and highlight through the list (i.e. background: red on the highlighted option) every few seconds and loop through it.  Is this possible?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kc1uhi?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts

Comment: What you want to highlight? You mean you want to update the list on an interval of few seconds?

Comment: No, I want to highlight one item in the list every few seconds

Comment: you mean changing background or something?

Comment: Yes, change the background of the item

Comment: added the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Did you check answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update class of your option dynamically and assign it in `mat-option` as:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [ngClass]="food.class" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Component**

```
foods = [
  {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak', class: 'highlight'},
  {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza', class: ''},
  {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos', class: 'highlight'}
];
```

You can write your logic to update `foods` on some interval according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to reset selectbox after a few second(you may need to implements import =>> **{ Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';** ) then highlight others, please refer below code: -

For you testing purpose, please follow below replacement in your ***stackbliz***  and it works well then try to add your own logic for further implementation.

```js
    import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    /**
     * @title Basic select
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'select-overview-example',
      templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
    })
    export class SelectOverviewExample implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect;
    foods = [
      {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak', class: 'highlight'},
      {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza', class: ''},
      {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos', class: 'highlight'}
    ];
      alive = true;
      selectedFood: any;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.selectedFood = this.foods[1];
    Observable.timer(0, (10000))
            .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.updateData();
            });
// PS: if you would like to stop resetting select box, you can assign **this.alive=false;** on a specific logic.
    }
    updateData() {
      console.log('updating data');
      this.foods = [
      {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak', class: ''},
      {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza', class: 'highlight'},
      {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos', class: ''}
    ];
      this.selectedFood = this.foods[0];
      console.log(this.selectedFood);
    }
      click() {
        this.mySelect.open();
      }
    }


/**  Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```css
/** No CSS for this example */
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)] = "selectedFood" #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [ngClass]="food.class" [value]="food">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<button (click)="click()">click</button>

<!-- Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```